# Best practice - Java serial bluetooth connection HC-05

Tags: java, bluetooth, arduino

What is currently the best best practice to connect with a Java application to a HC-05 Bluetooth module (Arduino)?
Bluecove or something else?
If so, are there any examples you can recommend for Bluecove with HC-05 connection?

Comment: Were you able to get on in this issue? I'm also interested in this. Please tell us if you achieved any progress. Thx

Comment: I think i once connected to a bluetooth device with the [jSerialComm](http://fazecast.github.io/jSerialComm/) library, since those bluetooth device would also be listed as serial devices. It is straight forward and easy to do. The only thing that could be a problem is, that you could need some Drivers for Windows.

Answer (score 7):

Some time ago i had the same question. In the meanwhile i found a way to communicate with my HC-05 via java. I am using blueCove - maybe there are other libraries but this works for me. Here is what i did:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.bluetooth.DeviceClass;
import javax.bluetooth.DiscoveryAgent;
import javax.bluetooth.DiscoveryListener;
import javax.bluetooth.LocalDevice;
import javax.bluetooth.RemoteDevice;
import javax.bluetooth.ServiceRecord;
import javax.bluetooth.UUID;
import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.microedition.io.StreamConnection;

public class HC05 {

    boolean scanFinished = false;
    RemoteDevice hc05device;
    String hc05Url;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new HC05().go();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(HC05.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private void go() throws Exception {
        //scan for all devices:
        scanFinished = false;
        LocalDevice.getLocalDevice().getDiscoveryAgent().startInquiry(DiscoveryAgent.GIAC, new DiscoveryListener() {
            @Override
            public void deviceDiscovered(RemoteDevice btDevice, DeviceClass cod) {
                try {
                    String name = btDevice.getFriendlyName(false);
                    System.out.format("%s (%s)\n", name, btDevice.getBluetoothAddress());
                    if (name.matches("HC.*")) {
                        hc05device = btDevice;
                        System.out.println("got it!");
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void inquiryCompleted(int discType) {
                scanFinished = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void serviceSearchCompleted(int transID, int respCode) {
            }

            @Override
            public void servicesDiscovered(int transID, ServiceRecord[] servRecord) {
            }
        });
        while (!scanFinished) {
            //this is easier to understand (for me) as the thread stuff examples from bluecove
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }

        //search for services:
        UUID uuid = new UUID(0x1101); //scan for btspp://... services (as HC-05 offers it)
        UUID[] searchUuidSet = new UUID[]{uuid};
        int[] attrIDs = new int[]{
            0x0100 // service name
        };
        scanFinished = false;
        LocalDevice.getLocalDevice().getDiscoveryAgent().searchServices(attrIDs, searchUuidSet,
                hc05device, new DiscoveryListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void deviceDiscovered(RemoteDevice btDevice, DeviceClass cod) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void inquiryCompleted(int discType) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void serviceSearchCompleted(int transID, int respCode) {
                        scanFinished = true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void servicesDiscovered(int transID, ServiceRecord[] servRecord) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < servRecord.length; i++) {
                            hc05Url = servRecord[i].getConnectionURL(ServiceRecord.NOAUTHENTICATE_NOENCRYPT, false);
                            if (hc05Url != null) {
                                break; //take the first one
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

        while (!scanFinished) {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }

        System.out.println(hc05device.getBluetoothAddress());
        System.out.println(hc05Url);

        //if you know your hc05Url this is all you need:
        StreamConnection streamConnection = (StreamConnection) Connector.open(hc05Url);
        OutputStream os = streamConnection.openOutputStream();
        InputStream is = streamConnection.openInputStream();

        os.write("1".getBytes()); //just send '1' to the device
        os.close();
        is.close();
        streamConnection.close();
    }
}
```

In my environment there are some other devices available but i filtered the result for HC.*. This is the console output from NetBeans:

```
run:
BlueCove version 2.1.0 on winsock
HC-05 (98D331FD157C)
got it!
Nintendo RVL-blabla(00000000FFFF)
GT-N7100 (00000000EEEE)
98D399999999
btspp://98D399999999:1;authenticate=false;encrypt=false;master=false
BlueCove stack shutdown completed
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 14 seconds)
```

Once you know the url of your HC-05 (btspp://...) you are able to connect without scanning for all devices and without searching for the services. This is much faster and the code is reduced to a few lines.

Here is my arduino code to do something with the data: Switching the board LED (pin 13) on when sending '1' and off if sending '0':

```
/*
 * Bluetooth-Modul anschliessen: +5, GND, 
 * Tx an Arduino Rx(Pin 0)
 * Rx an Arduino Tx(Pin 1)
 * 
 * Per Handy mit App 'ArduDroid by Techbitar':
 * -Menü 'Connect me to a Bluetooth device
 * -Send Data "A" oder "B" schaltet die LED auf Pin 13 aus bzw. an
 * und gibt Rückmeldung 'LED:on' oder 'LEF:off'.
 * 
 * https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sXs7S048eIo
 * 
 * Alternativ mit JavaCode: projekt 'MrBlue'
 */

int ledPin = 13;
int cmd = -1;
int flag = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    cmd = Serial.read();
    flag = 1;
  }

  if (flag == 1) {
    if (cmd == '0') {
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
      Serial.println("LED: off");
    } else if (cmd == '1') {
      digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
      Serial.println("LED: on");
    } else {
      Serial.print("unknown command: ");
      Serial.write(cmd);
      Serial.print(" (");
      Serial.print(cmd, DEC);
      Serial.print(")");

      Serial.println();
    }

    flag = 0;    
    cmd = 65;
  }

  Serial.flush();
  delay(100);
}
```

And here is the fancy protocol between me and my HC-05:
[image]

The connections between my Arduino Uno and the HC-05:
[image]

Comment: I'm getting "enter a code" window on Win7... I have no idea what to insert since HC-05 doesn't actually produce any code (and where i can take a look on it???)

Comment: I read somewhere 'try using code 1234 or 0000'. 1234 was the default on my device.

Comment: @chris bit of a longshot, but is is possible for you to share a copy of the "fancy protocol" version of your communication between PC and HC-05. I am trying to get mine working, and I have send working, but not receive. From what I understand, I'll need to have some form of loop to scan the input stream. I have been scouring the internet for a few days and can only find the one solution on the bluecove docs, which looks like it would lock the program into an infinite loop, preventing any other operation. As you have multiple windows open, yours seems more likely to not jam the main program

Comment: You should not provide 5V to your RX on HC-05 there is logic level = 3.6V so you should use some resistance eg.1-2 to divide volts

Answer (score -1):

for " enter a code" window on win7 use : 1234 or 0000

Comment: I feel that you might be quoting from somewhere. Please name the source. Also, explaining why this might help would improve the impression of your post, as well as spending a little effort on language details, like punctuation, capitalisation. Please have a look at [answer] and [tour] and https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help